# NextJs - question on data fetching in a functional component

Tags: typescript, types, next.js, fetch, react-functional-component

I am new to typescript & NextJs. I have a question about this code

```js
const Home: NextPage = ({characters}:any) => {  
return (      
  <div>          
    {JSON.stringify(characters)}        
 </div>  
)}

export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps = async(context)=>{  
const res = await fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")  
const { results } = await res.json();  
return{    
      props:{      
            characters: results   }  }}


export default Home
```

The `const getStaticProps` returns an object prop, how does it get into  Home? I don't see home calling it

`Home: NextPage = ({characters}:any)`  it's expecting a characters `object` of `any`. How does it know that prop is the one to read from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props):

> Exporting a function called getStaticProps will pre-render a page at build time using the props returned from the function

These can only be declared on page components, because of that, at build-time each page could only have one of these functions, if it has, it will execute and send the props down to the page component.

Comment: aah ok i see, and does it look for the exact props name of props?

or can i name the return props whatever else?
such as :
`
return{
 otherPropsName:
        characters: results
}
`

Comment: you'll return an object from `getStaticProps`, inside of it, you can set predefined values. for example, `redirect`, `props` and others. In the `props` property, you can store whatever values you want, as long as they can be JSON serialized, and you'll be able to retrieve these values on the props your component receives as parameter